# Lie brackets of vector fields along a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, vector-fields

With reference in https://archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n82/mode/1up, where it is said $[u,v]=0$ that in this case are the vector fields below.

Given two vector fields along a geodesic $\gamma$ in a manifold given by:
$$\partial_t \Gamma=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\quad \quad \partial_s \Gamma=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$$

> With $\gamma:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow \cal{M}$ and the geodesic variation
> of $\gamma$ given by
> $\Gamma:[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\times\mathbb{I}\rightarrow \cal{M}$ s.t.
> $\Gamma(0,t)=\gamma(t)$ and $\forall s\in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ we
> have that $t\rightarrow \Gamma(s,t)$ is a geodesic.

> Now let
> $d\Gamma_p:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow T_{\Gamma(p)}\cal{M}$
> s.t. $\partial_s\Gamma=(d\Gamma)_p(\frac{d}{ds},0)$ and
> $\partial_t\Gamma=(d\Gamma)_p(0,\frac{d}{dt})$. 
> In particular when
> we consider $p\in\gamma$ then $\partial_t\Gamma(0,t)=\dot \gamma(t)$
> and $\partial_s\Gamma(0,t):=J(t)$.
> These two last vector fields
> along $\gamma$ are the vector fields of my interest that I have
> written in coordinates considering $\Gamma(t,s)=x^{\alpha}(s,t)$. In
> addition I know that
> $\nabla_s\partial_t\Gamma=\nabla_t\partial_s\Gamma$ and obviously
> $\nabla_t\partial_t\Gamma=0$, since $\gamma$ is a geodesic.

$\textbf{I want to prove that $[\partial_t \Gamma,\partial_s \Gamma]=0$}$, where $\textbf{[}\quad\textbf{]}$ represent the Lie brackets.

To do this I have developed the following idea:
$$[\partial_t \Gamma,\partial_s \Gamma]=\Big[\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}, \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\Big]=\Big(\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}-\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial t}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}=\Big(\frac{\partial^2 x^\beta}{\partial t\partial s}-\frac{\partial^2 x^\beta}{\partial s\partial t}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}=0$$
$\textbf{My doubt: }$I am not sure of the second and above all of the third equality, where I have thought to write $\displaystyle\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 x^\beta}{\partial s\partial t}$.

Do you think what I have done it is correct? If not can you tell me where there are the mistakes and how can I prove that the lie brackets give me a  null vector in this case?

Comment: The problem is that $[\partial_t \Gamma, \partial_s \Gamma]$ doesn't make sense as a Lie bracket, because $\partial_t \Gamma$ and $\partial_s\Gamma$ aren't vector fields on the manifold. In your argument, the problem arises in your third equality -- The expression $\partial x^\beta/\partial t$ is a function of $s$ and $t$, so it doesn't make sense to differentiate it with respect to $x^\alpha$.

Comment: @JackLee But they are vector on a geodesic on a manifold so the lie brackets give me another vector field on the geodesic on the manifold...you say that it has no sense, but it is an excercise left to the reader

Comment: OK, what is the definition of the Lie bracket of two vector fields along a geodesic?

Comment: I don't know...I am confused...I thought it was what I have written above but you have said it has no sense. Can you tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: This is an argument in the context of general relativity

Comment: Precisely it is used to find out the jacobi equation

Comment: I see. Without seeing the actual text, I can't tell if they're just being sloppy, or they've given a rigorous definition that makes sense of expressions like this. I suspect the former. If you'd like to see a proof of the Jacobi equation that doesn't make use of meaningless Lie bracket expressions, check out Theorem 10.1 in my _Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds_ (2nd ed.).

Comment: @JackLee, the OP's comments helped elucidate what this is about. It appears that $\Gamma(s,t)$ is a map $\Gamma: I_1 \times I_2 \rightarrow M$, where $M$ is a Riemannian or Lorentzian manifold, so $\partial_s\Gamma$ and $\partial_t\Gamma$ are the push-forwards of the vector fields $\partial_s$ and $\partial_t$. Since the Lie bracket is invariant under pushforward, the desired equation follows. In fact, the OP's proof appears to be correct. The map $\Gamma$ is probably a variation of constant speed geodesics, so one of these vector fields is in probably a Jacobi field.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n81/mode/1up here (at page 66-67) there is the context and the argument treated. The vector $\partial_t\Gamma$ and $\partial_s\Gamma$ are in this $u$ and $v$

Comment: @Deane do you think the third equality that I have written is correct? $\gamma$ is the variation geodesic of $\gamma$ (the geodesic where $\partial_t\Gamma$ and $\partial_s\Gamma$ are vector fields

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "$\gamma$ is the variation geodesic of $\gamma$"

Comment: In any case, this calculation does not require anything about geodesics. It's just a basic fact of any map from one manifold to another. Here $\Gamma$ is a smooth map from a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a manifold $M$. You're just choosing local coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^m)$ and doing the whole calculation using them,

Comment: @Deane -- I understand the context. But in general the pushforward of a vector field under a smooth map is not a vector field. It's a section of the pulled-back tangent bundle, but as far as I know there's not a well-defined Lie bracket of such things.

Comment: @Deane, sorry there is a typo on my comment...$\Gamma$ is a smooth map from a rectangle to the manifold $M$, and it is the variation geodesic of $\gamma$. The calculation that I have done is done in coordinates, but I am not sure about the third equality. Can you help me?

Comment: @JackLee, yes. I keep tripping over this.

Comment: As @JackLee says, you are trying to compute something that is ill-defined, namely the Lie bracket of the pushforward of two vector fields. To demonstrate that a Jacobi field satisfies the Jacobi equation, you have to do a similar calculation but it's not a Lie bracket. Jack Lee's book is a good place to read about this.

Comment: @Deane But sorry in this book (archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n81/mode/1up here (at page 66-67)) it is said explicitly that these lie brackets give me a null vector!!

Comment: Does the book assume that $\Gamma$ is an immersion (i.e., $\partial_s\Gamma, \partial_t\Gamma$ are linearly independent)?

Comment: @Deane I have edited the question with alll informations that I have on $\Gamma$!

Comment: I looked at the book. Pages 66-67 do not contain the term "Lie bracket". The author does appear to be aware of the issue and deals with it in chapters 13 and 16. In particular, he shows that if two vector fields on the domain are "$\phi$-related" to vector fields in the range, then you can define the Lie bracket of the pushforward of the two vector fields in the domain. I repeat my recommendation that you look at Jack Lee's book (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319917542), if you want to understand this better.

Comment: When it is said $u$ and $v$ commute mean that if we apply the commutator as operator we obtain zero, not?

Comment: I took another quick look and don't have time to discuss this further. Note that he refers to Chapter 16 in this discussion and uses the term $H$-related. I don't know if he got it all correct, but it does look like he tried.

Comment: @cely: For mathematical things which are ill defined I suggest you ask here: physics.stackexchange.com.  they are used to abuse